# How to create an audio CD which can be played in every CD player?

Tags: compact-disc, cd-burning

I'm burning my own audio recordings on CDs and I want to be certain that the discs can be played in every CD player, not only in new models, which may even support plain MP3 files. Can I use a rewritable CD (CD-RW)? If [CD-RW is less compatible](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/all-about-cd-r-and-cd-rw/), does CD-R *always* work? How to convert files to a supported audio format and burn in a correct hierarchy?

I experimented with [Burrrn](https://alternativeto.net/software/burrrn/) (no longer in development) -- my newer portable CD player can play the CD (CD-R), but Pioneer PD-207 doesn't detect the disc.

Comment: Supported audio-format ??? There is only 1 format for Audio-CD's. If you mean Data-CD containing audio-files (like MP3, WAV, etc.) then MOST CD players won't be able to play them.

Comment: @Tonny I don't mean data CDs.

Comment: I figured as much, but it isn't really clear from the question if you understand the difference between audio and data CD's. Especially since you also ask about compatible audio-formats (which makes sense for data-CD's but not for audio-CD's).

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that a burned CD will work in *every* CD player.  However, I do remember older CD players sometimes had issues with CD-RW.  So you should stick with CD-R.  However, I do remember my portable CD player wouldnt play any burned CDs.  As Tonny said in the comment, burn slow.  Older CD players had issues with CDs burned with a high speed.  Stick with 1x-4x speeds, the slower the better.

Comment: Totally agree and burn SLOWLY. Use 4-speed at most. Even if your burner can do 48 or 52 speed burns it does make a HUGE difference in quality of the end-result. Especially with the cheap CD-R media.

Comment: @Tonny thats right.  I completely forgot about burn speeds.

Answer (score -1):

I've been doing music recordings on location since before they invented CDs.
I maintain an early Pro level Tascam CD recorder as a compatibility reference.  If a disk records and plays on that machine, it will do so anywhere. I've experimented with several different products. My wife hangs them on her fruit trees to scare off the birds.
The duplicating co. I've used for years uses disks made by Victor Advanced Media Co.,Ltd.  Japan.  Bulk marketed under the "VALUE" trade mark.  Victor recently stopped making optical media but created a subsidiary, "JVC Victor.....".
Never had a failure, recording or playing on any machine.  Even on old car players.
I'll be calling my duplicator, this week, to see if they're still available.  If so, I'll leave another note.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).